# What STL algorithm can determine if exactly one item in a container satisfies a predicate?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, counting, std

I need an STL algorithm that takes a predicate and a collection and returns `true` if one and only one member of the collection satisfies the predicate, otherwise returns `false`.

How would I do this using STL algorithms?

E.g., to replace the following with STL algorithm code to express the same return value.

```
int count = 0;

for( auto itr = c.begin(); itr != c.end(); ++itr ) {
    if ( predicate( *itr ) ) {
      if ( ++count > 1 ) {
        break;
      }
    }
}

return 1 == count;
```

Comment: count_if handles the algorithm part. You'll still need to check ==1

Comment: Are you looking for [std::any_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)?

Comment: Is the range sorted?

Comment: @JesperJuhl `std::any_of()` returns whether AT LEAST 1 element satisfies the predicate. There may be more than 1. `std::any_of()` does not return whether EXACTLY 1 element satisfies the predicate, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Galik: if the range is partitioned according to predicate, we just have to check `predicate(c[1])`...

Comment: The code you started with is, in my view, much clearer than the answer you accepted. Why encode what you're trying to do with library calls apparently just for terseness?

Comment: @imallett difficult for me to object because the answer is mine, but with the same reasoning you could say that using any algorithm is pointless, as they do the same as the handwritten loop. Irrespective of my answer I dont agree that the handwritten is more clear. what both codes do is: find one element then find another one. In the algorithms version one can understand that by reading the code begin to end, while in the one with the loop you have to consider the code as a whole to see what is going on

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Two things come to my mind:

[`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) and then compare the result to `1`.

To avoid traversing the whole container in case eg the first two elements already match the predicate I would use two calls looking for matching elements. Something along the line of

```
auto it = std::find_if(begin,end,predicate);
if (it == end) return false;
++it;
return std::none_of(it,end,predicate);
```

Or if you prefer it more compact:

```
auto it = std::find_if(begin,end,predicate); 
return (it != end) && std::none_of(std::next(it),end,predicate);
```

Credits goes to Remy Lebeau for compacting, Deduplicator for debracketing and Blastfurnance for realizing that we can also use [`none_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) the std algorithms.

Comment: I like the short-circuiting of the second option.

Comment: @NathanOliver I always strive to be as explicit as possible about what I actually want to do in the code, actually not that much for efficiency but mainly for clarity of the code. Nobody asked for the count over the whole container, so why make the code lie about it. unfortunately its not always as easy as in this example

Comment: Someone will probably disagree with me on this, vocally, but I just feel compelled to say it. It's answers like this that remind me about the beauty that can sometimes be found in the standard algorithm library.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)<sup>**†**</sup> to count and return if it is one.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // std::count_if
#include <vector>    // std::vector
#include <ios>       // std::boolalpha

template<class Iterator, class UnaryPredicate>
constexpr bool is_count_one(Iterator begin, const Iterator end, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    return std::count_if(begin, end, pred) == 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{ 2, 4, 3 };
    // true: if only one Odd element present in the container
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << is_count_one(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(),
                  [](const int ele) constexpr noexcept -> bool { return ele & 1; });
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>†</sup>**Update**: However, `std::count_if` counts entire element in the container, which is not good as the algorithm given in the question. The best approach using the standard algorithm collections has been mentioned in *[@formerlyknownas_463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500676/what-standard-algorithm-can-determine-if-exactly-one-of-a-container-satisfies-a/56500727#56500727)* 's answer.

That being said, OP's approach is also good as the above mentioned best standard approach, where a short-circuiting happens when `count` reaches `2`. If someone is interested in a non-standard algorithm template function for OP's approach, here is it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    // std::vector
#include <ios>       // std::boolalpha
#include <iterator>  // std::iterator_traits

template<class Iterator, class UnaryPredicate>
bool is_count_one(Iterator begin, const Iterator end, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type count{ 0 };
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if (pred(*begin) && ++count > 1) return false;
    }
    return count == 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{ 2, 3, 4, 2 };
    // true: if only one Odd element present in the container
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << is_count_one(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(),
                  [](const int ele) constexpr noexcept -> bool { return ele & 1; });
    return 0;
}
```

Now that can be **generalized**, by providing one more parameter, the number of `N` element(s) has/ have to be found in the container.

```
template<typename Iterator>
using diff_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type;

template<class Iterator, class UnaryPredicate>
bool has_exactly_n(Iterator begin, const Iterator end, UnaryPredicate pred, diff_type<Iterator> N = 1)
{
    diff_type<Iterator> count{ 0 };
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if (pred(*begin) && ++count > N) return false;
    }
    return count == N;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that misses the key requirement of not counting past 2.

Comment: I mean once count reaches 2, it is unnecessary to continue computing the predicate.

Comment: @WilliamKF Shamefully agree with that. The other answer shows a better alternative. In case, you are interested to convert your shown algorithm to a better version by packing them into a templated function, here is an example:https://wandbox.org/permlink/zej1d4L0J7RoS5PH which will short circuit as in your code.

Answer (score 11):

Starting from [formerlyknownas_463035818's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56500727/2156537), this can be generalized to seeing if a container has exactly `n` items that satisfy a predicate. Why? Because this is C++ and we're not satisfied until we can read email at compile time.

```
template<typename Iterator, typename Predicate>
bool has_exactly_n(Iterator begin, Iterator end, size_t count, Predicate predicate)
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
        return std::none_of(begin, end, predicate);
    }
    else
    {
        auto iter = std::find_if(begin, end, predicate);
        return (iter != end) && has_exactly_n(std::next(iter), end, count - 1, predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I was unable to read my email. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks. On a more serious note, why not go one step further and make the `n` a compile-time value (template non-type parameter) as well?

Comment: @CodyGray: If `n = 10000`, does the compiler recursively generate 10000 templates, or are modern compilers smart enough to do tail-call elimination in the templating step?

Comment: @CodyGray I believe the `std::email_client` concept has been pushed back to C++23.

Comment: @CodyGray I've tried your idea here: https://repl.it/repls/BossyIdealDatawarehouse. The problem is, as mentioned by @Kevin, that a new function is generated for every value of `n`. If you want to know whether a std::vector<int> has exactly  100,000 zeros in it, the program won't compile.

Comment: @Kevin The compiler can't do tail-call optimization because the functions generated are different. Every value of `n` gets a new function which calls the function for `n-1`. This leads to compilation failing. See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: To the idea to use `n` as a template parameter: I think the opposite is true: the recursive implementation can be easily unwound and inlined by a compiler. So, I think it is better here to stay with the recursive implementation (`n` as a function parameter) and let the compiler to optimize/inline recursive calls (for smaller `n`-s).

Answer (score 9):

#### Using [`std::not_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn) to negate a predicate

As the core of the algorithm of this question (as has been elegantly covered by combining [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) and [`std::none_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56500727/4573247)), with short-circuiting upon failure,  is to scan a container for a unary predicate and, when met, continue scanning the rest of the container for *the negation* of the predicate, I will mention also the negator `std::not_fn` introduced in C++17, replacing the less useful `std::not1` and `std::not2` constructs.

We may use `std::not_fn` to implement the same predicate logic as the accepted answer (`std::find_if` conditionally followed by `std::none_of`), but with somewhat different semantics, replacing the latter step (`std::none_of`) with [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) over the *negation* of the unary predicate used in the first step (`std::find_if`). E.g.:

```
// C++17
#include <algorithm>   // std::find_if
#include <functional>  // std::not_fn
#include <ios>         // std::boolalpha
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>  // std::next
#include <vector>

template <class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
constexpr bool one_of(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p) {
  auto it = std::find_if(first, last, p);
  return (it != last) && std::all_of(std::next(it), last, std::not_fn(p));
}

int main() {
  const std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 5, 6, 7};
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Exactly one even number : "
            << one_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const int n) {
                 return n % 2 == 0;
               });  // Exactly one even number : true
}
```

---

#### A parameter pack approach for static size containers

As I’ve already limited this answer to C++14 (and beyond), I’ll include an alternative approach for static size containers (here applied for `std::array`, specifically), making use of `std::index_sequence` combined with parameter pack expansion:

```
#include <array>
#include <ios>         // std::boolalpha
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>     // std::(make_)index_sequence

namespace detail {
template <typename Array, typename UnaryPredicate, std::size_t... I>
bool one_of_impl(const Array& arr, const UnaryPredicate& p,
                 std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  bool found = false;
  auto keep_searching = [&](const int n){
      const bool p_res = found != p(n);
      found = found || p_res;
      return !found || p_res;
  };
  return (keep_searching(arr[I]) && ...) && found;
}
}  // namespace detail

template <typename T, typename UnaryPredicate, std::size_t N,
          typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
auto one_of(const std::array<T, N>& arr,
            const UnaryPredicate& p) {
  return detail::one_of_impl(arr, p, Indices{});
}

int main() {
  const std::array<int, 5> a{1, 3, 5, 6, 7};
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Exactly one even number : "
            << one_of(a, [](const int n) {
                 return n % 2 == 0;
               });  // Exactly one even number : true
}
```

This will also short-circuit upon early failure (“found more than one”), but will contain a few more simple boolean comparisons than in the approach above.

**However**, note that this approach could have its draw-backs, particularly for optimized code for container inputs with many elements, as is pointed out by @PeterCordes in a comment below. Citing the comment (as comments are not guaranteed to persist over time):

> Just because the size is static doesn't mean that fully unrolling the loop with templates is a good idea. In the resulting asm, this needs a branch every iteration anyway to stop on found, so that might as well be a loop-branch. CPUs are good at running loops (code caches, loopback buffers). Compilers will fully unroll static-sized loops based on heuristics, but probably *won't* roll this back up if `a` is huge. So your first `one_of` implementation has the best of both worlds already, assuming a normal modern compiler like gcc or clang, or maybe MSVC

Comment: Just because the size is static doesn't mean that fully unrolling the loop with templates is a good idea.  In the resulting asm, this needs a branch every iteration anyway to stop on found, so that might as well be a loop-branch.  CPUs are good at running loops (code caches, loopback buffers).  Compilers will fully unroll static-sized loops based on heuristics, but probably *won't* roll this back up if `a` is huge.  So your first `one_of` implementation has the best of both worlds already, assuming a normal modern compiler like gcc or clang, or maybe MSVC.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the feedback, good point(s)! As I currently don’t get to use modern C++ features in my work, I fear some of my answers might become blindly biased to using particular “new” (non-legacy ...) core language features I find interesting to practice on. I’ll add your comment as a quote at the end of my answer, if it’s ok? As comments may not persist over time.